# "error" : "MismatchSendedId" when trying to send a Web Push notification

Tags: curl, google-cloud-messaging, firebase-cloud-messaging, web-push, progressive-web-apps

I'm following this [guide](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/getting-started/codelabs/push-notifications/) to learn about web push implementation. I've followed the guide until I encountered a problem when using curl to send a notification:

```
curl --header "Authorization: key=<PUBLIC_API_KEY>" --header "Content-Type: application/json" https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send -d "{\"registration_ids\":[\"<SUBSCRIPTION_ID>\"]}"
```

I changed the API Key and Subscription Id with my Firebase Cloud Messaging key and the Subscription ID generated when the notifications are accepted on the browser.

Still I get this error when executing curl:

> {"multicast_id":8346257587601342490,"success":0,"failure":1,"canonical_ids":0,"results":[{"error":"MismatchSenderId"}]}

I found this error related to android push notifications but not about web push so the other answers were not useful with my issue.

Has anyone experienced this issue? What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was also experiencing the same thing. Even after recheking a dozen of times that the manifest was properly written out and set and that the API_KEY and registration_ids are correct.
But I have now noticed that the problem was that I wasn't copying the whole url link.
Example if your endpoint url is:
endpoint: https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send/c_hMYQ0IJEg:APA91bHugFROB5EKLlwFKPjc7lRs_YZ7nBV655oftqdKPtzsmoz149d1BLVntgMpRnLHGqTVn6W7n7je4SoezFhfbUMdwxAot

Then the subsctionID will be "c_hMYQ0IJEg:APA91bHugFROB5EKLlwFKPjc7lRs_YZ7nBV655oftqdKPtzsmoz149d1BLVntgMpRnLHGqTVn6W7n7je4SoezFhfbUMdwxAot".

I had been using only the last part as in "APA91bHugFROB5EKLlwFKPjc7lRs_YZ7nBV655oftqdKPtzsmoz149d1BLVntgMpRnLHGqTVn6W7n7je4SoezFhfbUMdwxAot" and I guess that's why I had been getting the errors.

Comment: That was it! This is the correct answer, nice to know since the example form google used only that last part

Answer (score 0):

It means that the service worker installation is associated to a GCM sender that is different from the GCM sender that generated the API key.

From Pushpad [troubleshooting](https://pushpad.xyz/docs/troubleshooting):

> - Make sure that you have created and linked the `manifest.json`
> - Check that you have entered correctly the `gcm_sender_id` in the `manifest.json`
> - Check that you have entered correctly the `GCM API key`

If everything is correct you can also try to unsubscribe and resubscribe after you have set the correct `gcm_sender_id`.

Comment: Thanks for the response collimarco, the thing is that I have already tripled checked that the sender id and API key are matching and also used a completely different project sender id and API key on a new server port to make sure there was no configuration left from the last one, do you have any more advice on this issue?

Comment: @JorgeCuevas In the previous months I provided support to many users experiencing that error message and the errors were always those listed above -  A last guess: have you tried to **use GCM instead of Firebase?**